# NULLPOINTER at lambda expression

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I can't figure out why I'm getting a NPE where I've marked it below.  I've mocked the call to the `private` method `getLastAcceptedVersion` and the public call to `queryDao.getStatus`.  To add, I'm only learning about Java 8 lamdas at the moment, I guess this has something to do with where I'm going wrong.

```
public class myClass {

//members

public Optional<Object> getLastAccepted(Long id, Integer version) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(getLastAcceptedVersion(id, version))
            .map(v -> queryDao.getStatus(id, v));  ------ NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
   }

}
```

And my test case:

```
private MyClass myClass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());
private QueryDao queryDao = mock(QueryDao.class);
private Object obj = mock(Object.class);

@Test
public void testGetLastAccepted() throws Exception{
    PowerMockito.doReturn(1).when(myClass, "getLastAcceptedVersion" , anyLong(), anyInt());
    when(queryDao.getRegulatoryReportingStatusbyTradeId(anyLong(), anyInt())).thenReturn(obj);
    assertNotNull(myClass.getLastAccepted(anyLong(), anyInt()));
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dao.MyClass.lambda$getLastAccepted$0(myClass .java:57)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at dao.MyClass.getLastAccepted(myClass .java:57)
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace.

Comment: Please provide the detail of queryDao Class.

Comment: queryDao Class is an `interface`

Comment: Added stacktrace

Comment: It looks like `MyClass` has a `QueryDao` field, but you don't set it anywhere.

Comment: queryDao.getStatus(id, v) returning Optional value.?

Comment: @Michael this was it... thanks.  It's been a long night.

Comment: @xeon48 Sure, happy to help.